# Write SQL query output into text file/log file

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

How to write the output of SQL query to .txt file.
Here is what I am trying to do.
The SQL query is written inside a perl script.

```
use strict;
use DataObject;

# create new object, number of default values are set.
my $obj = new DataObject();

# set database server to connect
$obj->SetDBIdent('someDB');

# get fully qualified name
my $bv = $obj->GetTbl("bv");

# query string
my $sql = qq[
    select TOP 100 bv.book_price from $bv bv
    where bv.book_yield is null
    OUTPUT INTO '\\logs.txt'        
];

# Execute the query
my $resultSet = $obj->DoSql($sql);

# print the results
foreach my $row (@$resultSet) {
    print "$row->{book_price}\t";
```

Here is the error I get-->
   Can't execute statement:

```
select TOP 100 bv.book_price from acctdb.dbo.bv bv
where bv.book_yield is null
OUTPUT INTO '\logs.txt'

 Transaction Rolled Back
DBD::Sybase::st execute failed: Server message number=156 severity=15 state=2 line=4 server=SYBDEVtext=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTPUT'.
Statement=
    select TOP 100 bv.book_price from  bv
    where bv.book_yield is null
    OUTPUT INTO '\logs.txt'
```

Comment: I am not a Perl programmer, but I can tell you that `OUTPUT INTO '\\logs.txt'` is not valid in a SQL statement.  You would have to retrieve the data into your program and then output it from there.

Comment: Is there anyother way to redirect the output result of query into a text file.??

Comment: @AnnL. It may not be standard SQL, but it looks like `OUTPUT INTO` is [valid T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) (although all of the examples I saw include a list of columns, i.e. `OUTPUT foo INTO ...`).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Ah, yes, I'd forgotten you can do that.  But that clause is for use with data manipulation statements, not SELECTs.

Comment: Simply remove the `OUTPUT INTO '\\logs.txt'` from your query, open a filehandle, and change your `print` statements to write to the handle instead of `STDOUT`, e.g.: `my $file = 'logs.txt'; open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Failed to open '$file': $!";` and `foreach my $row (@$resultSet) { print $fh "$row->{book_price}\t"; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bcp` utility for this.
If you can run bat files from Perl then create bat file:

```
bcp "select TOP 100 book_price from  DatabaseName.SchemaName.bv where book_yield is null" queryout logs.txt -c -T
```